# How to remove fresh posts (latest news) on the main page?

Tags: posts, remote, newsletter

How to remove fresh posts (latest news) on the main page? I can't find how to remove the "fresh posts"(latest news), I don't need it. Themes the Virtue. Tell me please. Thank you in advance. See below pictures.

---

[image]

Comment: Are you use ready made theme or custom theme ?

Comment: @PratikPatel, I don't know.. how to find out? Just install own from `/wp-admin/theme-install.php?browse=featured`

Comment: Please go to your admin panel and open **Pages** option and find HOME page and check once if there is option for this section

Comment: @PratikPatel, Home not found - scr: [here](https://prnt.sc/m2y5xd)

Comment: @PratikPatel, this is a custom theme not for ready made theme.

Comment: i think from admin side you cant able to do any thing.you need to go to the theme file and need to edit the  index.php

Comment: @Adarsh that is not right way for this

Comment: @SergeyKiziev you have to create HOME page in admin panel and assign that page as a default static page from **Settings > Reading > A static page (select below)** and select your page there

Comment: @PratikPatel he need to remove the fresh section from the home page right?

Comment: Yes but if he removed that loop from index.php then what ever he add in back end side its not reflect on front end side may be. @Adarsh

Comment: @PratikPatel, I don't need a headline. I just need to remove the latest news. Can't? It was just clean. Because it will add a post from encoding. for example: `<?php $post_id_286 = get_post( 286 ); echo $post_id_286->post_content; ?>` you understand? Just remove the last post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to the problem. Very simple! Go to admin panel `yoursite/wp-admin` > Appearance > Theme Settings > Homepage Layout > The Layout Manager homepage > all Enabled to Disabled. Done! Now your Homepage is clean.

Here is a screenshot, I hope you understand. Have a nice day :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to remove the entire section outlined in red on your picture?

To do that, go into the admin > appearance > editor.  Then on the right, find home.php and click it to edit the file.

Remove the following code from the file and click "Update File" to save...

```
<?php if ( !have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="alert">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no results were found.', 'virtue' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_search_form(); 
endif; 

if( $summary == 'full' ){
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'fullpost' ); 
    endwhile; 
} else {
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'templates/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile; 
}

/**
* @hooked virtue_pagination - 10
*/
do_action( 'virtue_pagination' );
?>
```

**Important Note**

This will make an edit directly to your theme.  A better way to do this is to make a [CHILD THEME](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), then edit the file there.  This will prevent you from losing any edits when your theme updates.

Comment: Yes, to be clean. You gave me coding - does not help. as before... cache does not help.

Comment: What do u mean my code didn't help?  You go into that file and remove the code, it will 100% work

Comment: Yes, I know how to remove. But alas, no, does not help.